# sqlalchemy: column_prefix causes issues accessing model attributes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I went searching w/o result in a way to get the integer value or the boolean value from an object model created via sqlalchemy,

I mean i can add it and it works flawless but i cant get the integer value or the boolean value all i get when i tried to print it is the object name:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column,Integer,String,Boolean,Sequence
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import json
class Bookmarks(object):
    pass
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
engine = create_engine('postgresql://u:p@localghost/asd', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

class Tramo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tramos'
    __mapper_args__ = {'column_prefix':'tramos'}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nombre = Column(String)
    tramo_data = Column(String)
    estado = Column(Boolean,default=True)

    def __init__(self,nombre,tramo_data):
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.tramo_data=tramo_data

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[id:%s][nombre:%s][tramo:%s]" % (getattr(self, 'id'),     self.nombre,self.tramo_data)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

tabla = Tramo.__table__
metadata = Base.metadata
metadata.create_all(engine)

b=Tramo('tramo1','adadas')

session.add(b)
session.commit()
print b
print b.id
```

its prints

```
[id:tramos.id][nombre:tramo1][tramo:adadas]
tramos.id
```

i cant get to print the id value, looks like the object column is in there but it doesn't return the value ot the property

i even use

```
session.refresh(b)
```

after the add but the result is the same.

Comment: Have you tried print int(b.id)

Comment: this is what i get -- 
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Column'

Comment: looks like the prefix is used for the object name and not for the ddl side of the object.

Comment: Why are you using `getattr(self, 'id')` instead of just `self.id`? You're printing the id after the object is committed, so its id attribute will be populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [Naming All Columns with a Prefix](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapper_config.html#column-prefix):

> ...prefix to the **mapped** attribute names relative to the
>   (**table**) column name ...

Since you define the mapped attributes in your class, I do not think it does what you desire.

**Solution-1:** remove the `'column_prefix':'tramos'` from your `__mapper_args__`

**Solution-2:** `print b.tramosid` will print its id. You would need to change the `__repr__` accordingly:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "[id:%s][nombre:%s][tramo:%s]" % (getattr(self, 'tramosid'), self.nombre, self.tramo_data)
```

Comment: thanks i already noticed it but  i didnt want to respond to myself. again thanks to you

Comment: @Freaktor: Thanks, but if you found a solution which worked for you, you should have posted it. This is encouraged and will help others.

Comment: i didnt posted it right away because i had to wait and when i come back (the next day) you posted the solution.